# Using vendor specific primitives in portable VHDL

Tags: vhdl

My project is written in portable VHDL (mainly developed in GHDL), but I would like to take advantage of vendor specific primitives (e.g. a multiplier) when they are available.

E.g. in C/C++ you can use #ifdef to conditionally select different code snippets depending on things like CPU architecture or compiler vendor.

Is there anything similar that you can use in VHDL, e.g. to distinguish between Xilinx or Altera/Intel targets?

Comment: You could write a portable Entity, and choose one of several vendor-specific Architectures with a configuration statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate` statements and vendor specific entities + architectures. The [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) makes heavily use of this technique to create [vendor independent IP cores](http://poc-library.readthedocs.io/en/release/WhatIsPoC/index.html).

Have for example a look at the On-Chip-Memory (ocram) abstraction layer of PoC: [PoC.mem.ocram.tdp](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/ocram/ocram_tdp.vhdl?ts=2#L171-L218)

```
gAltera: if not SIMULATION and (VENDOR = VENDOR_ALTERA) generate
    component ocram_tdp_altera
        generic (
            A_BITS      : positive;
            D_BITS      : positive;
            FILENAME    : string        := ""
        );
        port (
            clk1 : in   std_logic;
            clk2 : in   std_logic;
            ce1 : in    std_logic;
            ce2 : in    std_logic;
            we1 : in    std_logic;
            we2 : in    std_logic;
            a1   : in   unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);
            a2   : in   unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);
            d1   : in   std_logic_vector(D_BITS-1 downto 0);
            d2   : in   std_logic_vector(D_BITS-1 downto 0);
            q1   : out std_logic_vector(D_BITS-1 downto 0);
            q2   : out std_logic_vector(D_BITS-1 downto 0)
        );
    end component;
begin
    -- Direct instantiation of altsyncram (including component
    -- declaration above) is not sufficient for ModelSim.
    -- That requires also usage of altera_mf library.

    ram_altera: ocram_tdp_altera
        generic map (
            A_BITS      => A_BITS,
            D_BITS      => D_BITS,
            FILENAME    => FILENAME
        )
        port map (
            clk1    => clk1,
            clk2    => clk2,
            ce1     => ce1,
            ce2     => ce2,
            we1     => we1,
            we2     => we2,
            a1      => a1,
            a2      => a2,
            d1      => d1,
            d2      => d2,
            q1      => q1,
            q2      => q2
        );
end generate gAltera;
```

Here, it instantiates a special entity for Altera devices. For other devices (Xilinx, Lattice) a generic VHDL implementation is used. Additionally, a special model is used for simulation, because the vendor primitives do not simulate the actual behavior as documented in the FPGA device documentations (e.g. in memory guides).